# Are there any tricks in building android layout quickly?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-theme

HTML has classes and many selectors to reuse css, but android only seems to have two difficult ways that using "theme" and "style", which just support single inheritance. Are there any tricks in imporving the efficiency of building android layout, or better tricks in using "theme" and "style"?